# HMS cancel notification with tag not working ( (HMS push kit)

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

I am integrating Huawei Push Kit (https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_push) in Flutter application.

I test to schedule a notification to notify every minutes in my Huawei phone, and I able to get the notification as expected. But when I tried to cancel the notification with *clearNotification()* function (shown below), the notification seem like not cancelled. Wondering do I miss out anything?

```
scheduleLocalNotification() async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> localNotification = {
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.TITLE: 'Notification Title',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.MESSAGE: 'Notification Message',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.TICKER: "OptionalTicker",
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.TAG: "push-tag",
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.BIG_TEXT: 'This is a bigText',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.SUB_TEXT: 'This is a subText',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.LARGE_ICON: 'ic_launcher',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.SMALL_ICON: 'ic_notification',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.COLOR: "white",
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.VIBRATE: true,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.VIBRATE_DURATION: 1000.0,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.ONGOING: false,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.DONT_NOTIFY_IN_FOREGROUND: false,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.AUTO_CANCEL: false,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.INVOKE_APP: false,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.ACTIONS: ["Yes", "No"],
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.REPEAT_TYPE: RepeatType.MINUTE,
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.FIRE_DATE:
            DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 1)).millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      };
      Map<String, dynamic> response =
          await Push.localNotificationSchedule(localNotification);
      print("Scheduled a local notification: " + response.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
  }  

clearNotification() async {
    Push.cancelNotificationsWithTag('push-tag');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Huawei Push Kit does not support *clearNotification()* function. You can use the Sending Downlink Messages API. There is an **auto_clear** parameter, and you can set message display duration, in milliseconds. Messages are automatically deleted after the duration expires.
Please refer to the following code:

```
{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "android": {
            "notification":{"body":"Big Boom Body！","click_action":{"type":3},"title":"Big Boom Title","auto_clear": 360000}
            },
    "token":[
    "token1",
    "token2"]
    }
}
```

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001070412173__section8686112674319)

Answer (score 0):

Your clearNotification function which calls `Push.cancelNotificationWithTag('push-tag')` is async.
Possibility is `Push.cancelNotificationWithTag` might get called before.
Either call it directly and not thru async function or add await.